# Fallo subiendo una foto a S3 usando XHR - Expo (React Native) - Error: "Stream Closed"

Tags: react-native, aws, expo, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

Tras actualizar Expo a SDK 49 (React Native v0.72.1) e intentar subir una imagen a AWS S3 usando XHR, devuelve el error "Stream Closed".

Las imágenes podían subirse perfectamente con Expo SDK 48 y versiones anteriores.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    function makeRequest(method, url, uploadData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve({
                    status: this.status,
                    responseText: this.responseText,
                });
            } else {
                console.warn('status -->', this.status,'responseText -->',                  this.responseText);
                reject(
                    new Error({
                        status: this.status,
                        responseText: this.responseText,
                    })
                );
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log('status -->', this.status, 
'; responseText -->', this.responseText);
            reject(
                new Error({
                    status: this.status,
                    responseText: xhr.responseText,
                    response: xhr.response,
                })
            );
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        xhr.send({
            uri: uploadData.uri,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            name: uploadData.fileName,
        });
    });
}
```

Cuando el usuario quiere subir una imagen a S3, primero la app envía una solicitud al servidor, y recibe una una URL prefirmada ("pre-signed URL"), y la imagen se sube desde el dispositivo cliente. Esto ha funcionado correctamente hasta la actualización a Expo SDK 49.

También preguntado en inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76664762/expo-react-native-s3-image-upload-returns-stream-closed-using-xhr).